# Crystal Report - Linq select statement finds nulls in fields

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use a Linq query to a custom crystal report in MyReports folder. However, crystal reports engine is complaining of nulls.

I have managed to make a blank for the Serial Number where it might be null, but DateTime is more of an issue for me.

I have tried:

```
InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate == null ? "" : subpat.InspectionDate,
```

But the error is:

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.DateTime?'
```

I would just want a blank result if null.

My Query:

```
        var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
        var tomorrow = today.AddDays(30);


        var dateresult = db.ClinicalINSs.GroupBy(d => d.ClinicalAssetID)
                   .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.NextInspectionDate)
                                     .Take(1));

        var ClinicalIDVM = (from s in dateresult.Where(q => q.NextInspectionDate <= tomorrow)
                           join co in db.ClinicalAssets on s.ClinicalAssetID equals co.ClinicalAssetID into AR
                           let subred = AR.OrderByDescending(subredASS => subredASS.ClinicalAssetID).FirstOrDefault()
                           join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID into AP
                           let subpat = AP.OrderByDescending(SubPATASS => SubPATASS.ClinicalAssetID).FirstOrDefault()
                           orderby s.NextInspectionDate descending


                           select new ClinicalIDVM
                           {
                               ClinicalAssetID = s.ClinicalAssetID,
                               ProductName = subred.ProductName,
                               SerialNo = subred.SerialNo == null ? "" : subred.SerialNo,
                               InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate,
                               NextInspectionDate = s.NextInspectionDate

                           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate == null ? (DateTime?)null : subpat.InspectionDate
```

or change type of InspectionDate to `string`, then you will do

```
InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate.HasValue 
? subpat.InspectionDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "";
```

**Updated**

```
 InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate == null ? (object) "" : subpat.InspectionDate
```

Comment: it would have to be a string to set blank? but ToString is missing 1 argument

Comment: You mean the second solution? What's the error you are getting?

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: What kind of `subpat.InspectionDate` type and sample value?

Comment: public Datetime? InspectionDate {get; set;} sample data would be: 31/12/2019

Comment: I'v just updated my answer, please take a look at. `InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate.HasValue 
    ? subpat.InspectionDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "";`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'

Comment: Did you change `InspectionDate` in `ClinicalIDVM` class from DateTime to string ?

Comment: Hmm.. should I have? if I change that i break the rest if code linked to it.

Comment: Because you want to set empty string, So you should use string instead.

Comment: but it doesn't work Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'string'

Comment: How about create new property like `InspectionDate_Str` to display purpose.

Comment: How about `InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate == null ? (object) "" : subpat.InspectionDate, `

Comment: @microchef I'v just updated my answer, please take a look at

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Either add extra fields for the report as Phong suggested or create a different model for the report. Another technique is to set the value to DateTime.MinValue if it is null and then conditionally suppress on the Crystal side if that is the case.

Comment: @Steve Greene I do think so, Use `DateTime.MinValue` would be great. Anyway, I didn't know why the OP doesn't react to my answer.